# Document Class/Template to recreate GM Owner's Manual

Tags: documentclass

I own a highly modified GM vehicle, and I'm interested in creating a "stock-alike" owners manual for my vehicle, incorporating my modifications.

I'm not necessarily looking for something that's perfectly identical to GM's manual, just something similar.  Stylistically, GM manuals have been pretty similar since the early 2000s, though they changed from two columns to three columns around 2010.  I'm not particular to either column count.

An example of a GM owner's manual: https://my.chevrolet.com/content/dam/gmownercenter/gmna/dynamic/manuals/2020/chevrolet/corvette/2020-chevrolet-corvette-owners-manual.pdf

An example page from a GM owner's manual:

[image: Example page from GM Owner's Manual]

Comment: Most of the work could be done using pdfpages.  tcolorbox would be useful here.

Comment: @JohnKormylo Maybe I'm missing something, but I don't understand how pdfpages would help.  I'm not looking to include the old manual; I want to create a new manual in the style of the old manual.  tcolorbox is a great suggestion!

Comment: Those things are HUGE!  I attempted to replace my car stereo manual with a PDF, but eventually gave up.

Comment: You can download the PDF at http://www.elfsoft2000.com//temp/manual.pdf and the source at http://www.elfsoft2000.com//temp/manual.tex